# Shell script to convert a string from one form to another

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have two strings

```
internal func add(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int
add(a:b:)
```

How can I make the first string convert into the second string. I can do this in programming languages, but unable to figure out a solution for bash script that I need.

Essentially whats needed is anything before (and including) `func` should be trimmed and anything following (and including) `->` should be removed and the type of variables should be removed. All spaces should also go.

Also, I tried using regex. I made `(?:.*func\s(.*)\s->.*)` that takes out the `add(a: Int, b: Int)` from the 1st string, but, I am not sure, how to further eliminate this string.

I preferably need some help in bash using awk or sed but regex would also do well for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using SED:

```
string='internal func add(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int'

sed -e '
s/^.*func \+//
s/ *\->.*$//
s/:[^,)]\+/:/g
s/[, ]//g
' <<< "$string"
```

- `s/^.*func \+//` removes the front (`^`) part before `func`, `func`, and spaces after `func`;
- `s/ *\->.*$//` removes spaces followed by `->` and anything after it at the end of the string;
- `s/:[^,)]\+/:/g` removes the type names after colons;
- `s/[, ]//g` performs final cleanup by removing commas and spaces.

Comment: It does not remove `internal func` from the start.

Comment: @prabodhprakash, [proof](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMdzQ3OTNzRUMtcGc)

Comment: This is how it looks in terminal ```➜  bin string='internal func add(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int'

sed -e '
s/^.*func \+//
s/ *\->.*$//
s/:[^,)]\+/:/g
s/[, ]//g
' <<< "$string"
internalfuncadd(a:Intb:Int)```

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not get you.

Comment: @prabodhprakash, Press *Execute* button **[on this page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMdzQ3OTNzRUMtcGc)**. If you write it in single line, use semicolons: `sed -e 's/^.*func \+//; s/ *\->.*$//; s/:[^,)]\+/:/g; s/[, ]//g' <<< "$string"`

Comment: It works very well on the link you shared. But, does not give output on my computer. What could be possible reason.

Comment: @prabodhprakash, the most likely reason is that you are not running Bash, or running Bash that doesn't support here strings (`<<< "$string"`). Try something like this: `echo "$string" | sed .....`

Answer (score 3):

Using pure bash in "oneliner" style:

```
#!/bin/bash
str="internal func add(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int"
[[ $str =~ .*func[[:space:]](.*\(.*:).*,[[:space:]]?(.*:).*(\)) ]] && str="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
echo $str
```

It works even if the string doesn't have the space after the comma which seems optional.

Comment: How to use it? I mean, where to supply input string. I created `str` with original input. Also, it does not produce an output. Please could you see.

Comment: You must put your string in a var called str `str="internal func add(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int"` , then you put my pure bash line, and its all... you have the result on the $str var, you can echo the result `echo $str`

Comment: There is nothing in the output. I did same.

Comment: I am doing same, but not getting any output.

Comment: Using Rusman Osmanov url to put bash examples... http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNnRnV1ZSZDREUWc

Comment: Got it. It worked fine. I created a shell script and wrote this there with bash thing on top and it worked.

Comment: Nice to hear that. Don't forget to mark as resolved the post choosing the solution you preferred. Mine or the other which is good too! :)

Comment: Can you also write explanation around your script. How it works.

Comment: This does not work, when the input string is like `internal func zero() -> Int`

Comment: Also when string is: `internal func add(a: Int, b: Int, c:Int) -> Int`

Comment: It worked for the examples you put. We can't do more without more information... now you are changing the examples... you are adding the possibility to have no parameters for the func or to have more than two... is a different solution. Next time explain it better, is not my fault, try to put all the info at the beginning.

Comment: Well, that was expected, like in other answers. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

A solution in `perl` `regEx` as

```
perl -lne 'print "$1$2$3)" if /^.*func (\w+)(\(\w+:).*, (\w+:).*\).*$/ ' <<<"internal func add(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int"
add(a:b:)
```

where, `$1`, `$2` and `$3` are  the capturing groups and a small hack with  printing `)` at end.

If your shell does not support `here-strings(<<<)`, just do

```
echo "internal func add(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int" | perl -lne 'print "$1$2$3)" if /^.*func (\w+)(\(\w+:).*, (\w+:).*\).*$/ ' 
add(a:b:)
```

Answer (score -2):

This is another `sed` approach to problem:

```
sed -r 's/^.*internal func *(\w+)\(([^)]*)\).*$/\1(\2)/;ta;b;:a;s/*(\w+:) *\w+,*/\1/g'
```

Comment: This takes into consideration the word `internal` too, which is not required by the question.

Comment: no, it doesn't. Group expressions don't even touch it