# Regex to convert a string form to another

Tags: regex

I've two strings of forms as below

1. `,ghjgc b: Int)`
2. `,ghjg, b: Int)`

I want the word before `:` to be removed - However, if the word is preceded by `,` - I don't want removal to happen. Thus, the output for the  strings above would be

1. `,ghjgc : Int)`
2. `,ghjg, b: Int)`

I've written the regex as `[^,] [^:[:space:]]*:` - however it gives output as

1. `,ghjg : Int)` `//note that 'c' at the end of ghjg is also removed`
2. `,ghjg, b: Int)` `//this is as expected`

This problem is happening probably because at the start of regex, I have `[^,]` that also adds one character before `space` a part of regex. Need help in getting this fixed

I do much more processing on the string and thus my sed command looks like:

`sed -e '
s/^.*func \{1,\}//
s/ *\->.*$//
s/:[^,)]\{1,\}/:/g
s/(?<!,) [^:[:space:]]+:/\1:/g
s/[, ]//g
' <<< "$string"`

and I am getting compiler error at 5th line (line index starting from 1)

Comment: Note that `(?<!,) [^:[:space:]]+:` cannot be used with `sed` since the POSIX regex flavor does not support lookarounds (here, the `(?<!,)` is a negative lookbehind, a lookaround, making sure there is no `,` right before the current location, it will work with `perl`, but not `sed`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
((^|[^,]) +)[^:[:space:]]+:
```

and replace with `\1:`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G8BbVD/2).

The point is to match either start of string or any char other than `,` + one or more spaces, and capture them into group #1, and then restore it with a `$1` backreference.

[SED demo](https://ideone.com/rl9hFr):

```
echo ",ghjgc b: Int)" | sed -E 's/((^|[^,]) +)[^:[:space:]]+:/\1:/g'
```

or a BRE version ([demo](https://ideone.com/Z0Uwik)):

```
echo ",ghjgc b: Int)" | sed 's/\(\(^\|[^,]\) \{1,\}\)[^:[:space:]]\{1,\}:/\1:/g'
```

**OSX sed note**: The BRE version that you have to use does not support `\|`, so you can't use alternation, and you can't have a match at the start of the string or at the char other than `,` in the same regex. Use

```
's/\([^,] \{1,\}\)[^:[:space:]]\{1,\}:/\1:/g'
```

and then, if you need matches of this kind at the start of the string:

```
's/^\( *\)[^:[:space:]]\{1,\}:/\1:/'
```

Comment: I am using this regex in sed, to substitute. How can I use $1 substitution there?

Comment: You need to use `\1`.

Comment: You cannot use `(?<!,) [^:[:space:]]+:`. Sed does not support Perl-like constructs like lookbehind. So, you would like to use a BRE version, right?

Comment: Use `sed 's/\(\(^\|[^,]\) \{1,\}\)[^:[:space:]]\{1,\}:/\1:/g'`

Comment: I'm not aware of BRE version.

Comment: The `-E` option (or `-r` which depends on OS version) enables ERE regex syntax (Extended Regular Expressions). BRE means Basic Regular Expression syntax, it is used by default.

Comment: `sed -e 's/\(\(^\|[^,]\) \{1,\}\)[^:[:space:]]\{1,\}:/\1:/g' <<< ",ghjgc b: Int)"` has no impact on output.

Comment: and my file as `#!/bin/sh` written on the top.

Comment: So, try `sed -r 's/((^|[^,]) +)[^:[:space:]]+:/\1:/g'` (pass `-r` option to enable ERE syntax). Well, I do not know if you can apply it to just one regex there

Comment: `-r` is not available :-(

Comment: Ok, the culprit is the `|`. I think `'s/\([^,] \{1,\}\)[^:[:space:]]\{1,\}:/\1:/g'` might work. However, it will not match at the start of the string.

Comment: How to get rid of it

Comment: I updated the answer at the bottom with the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Search using:

```
(,[^,[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+)[a-zA-Z0-9]+:
```

and replace using:

```
\1:
```

Here using a negated character class we are matching text that is not a comma or whitespace and capture it to be used as back-reference later.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oC0MFh/6)

**Sed command:**

```
sed -E 's/(,[^,[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+)[a-zA-Z0-9]+:/\1:/' file

,ghjgc : Int)
,ghjg, b: Int)
```

---

As per comments below OP can use this `sed` command:

```
sed -E '
s/(,[^,[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+)[a-zA-Z0-9]+:/\1:/
s/^.*func +//
s/ *->.*$//
' file
```

[Working Demo](http://Search%20using:%20%20(,[%5E,[:%20blank%20:]]+[[:%20blank%20:]]+)[%20a%20-%20zA%20-%20Z0%20-%209%20]+:%20%20and%20replace%20using:%20%20%5C1%20:%20%20Here%20using%20a%20negated%20character%20class%20we%20are%20matching%20text%20that%20is%20not%20a%20comma%20or%20whitespace%20and%20capture%20it%20to%20be%20used%20as%20back-reference%20later.%20%20RegEx%20Demo%20%20Sed%20command:%20%20sed%20-%20E%20's/(,[%5E,[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+)[a-zA-Z0-9]+:/%5C1:/'%20file%20,%20ghjgc%20:%20%20Int%20)%20%20,%20ghjg%20,%20b%20:%20%20Int%20)%20%20%20%20As%20per%20comments%20below%20OP%20can%20use%20this%20sed%20command:%20%20sed%20-%20E%20'%20s/(,[%5E,[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+)[a-zA-Z0-9]+:/%5C1:/%20s/%5E.*func%20+//%20s/%20*-%3E.*$//%20'%20file%20%20share%20%7C%20edit%20%7C%20delete%20%7C%20flag%20%20edited%2017%20secs%20ago%20%20answered%2058%20mins%20ago%20%20%20%20anubhava%20%20404k%2032%20184%20245%20%20StackExchange.ifUsing(%22editor%22,%20function%20()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20StackExchange.using(%22externalEditor%22,%20function%20()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20StackExchange.using(%22snippets%22,%20function%20()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20StackExchange.snippets.init();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%22code-snippets%22);%20%20StackExchange.ready(function()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20initTagRenderer(%22%22.split(%22%20%22),%20%22%22.split(%22%20%22));%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20StackExchange.using(%22externalEditor%22,%20function()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20Have%20to%20fire%20editor%20after%20snippets,%20if%20snippets%20enabled%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(StackExchange.settings.snippets.snippetsEnabled)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20StackExchange.using(%22snippets%22,%20function()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20createEditor();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20createEditor();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20function%20createEditor()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20prepareEditor(%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20heartbeatType:%20'edit',%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20convertImagesToLinks:%20false,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reputationToPostImages:%20null,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bindNavPrevention:%20true,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20postfix:%20%22-42225206%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onDemand:%20false,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20discardSelector:%20%22%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20,postId:42225206%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20setTimeout(function()%20%7B$('#wmd-input-42225206').focus();%7D,5);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%7D);%20%20Search%20using:%20%20%20%20%20%20(,[%5E,[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+)[a-zA-Z0-9]+:%20%20and%20replace%20using:%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C1:%20%20Here%20using%20a%20negated%20character%20class%20we%20are%20matching%20text%20that%20is%20not%20a%20comma%20or%20whitespace%20and%20capture%20it%20to%20be%20used%20as%20back-reference%20later.%20%20[RegEx%20Demo][1]%20%20**Sed%20command:**%20%20%20%20%20%20sed%20-E%20's/(,[%5E,[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+)[a-zA-Z0-9]+:/%5C1:/'%20file%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20,ghjgc%20:%20Int)%20%20%20%20%20,ghjg,%20b:%20Int)%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://regex101.com/r/oC0MFh/6%20%20---%20%20As%20per%20comments%20below%20OP%20can%20use%20this%20%60sed%60%20command:%20%20%20%20%20%20sed%20-E%20'%20%20%20%20%20s/(,[%5E,[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+)[a-zA-Z0-9]+:/%5C1:/%20%20%20%20%20s/%5E.*func%20+//%20%20%20%20%20s/%20*-%3E.*$//%20%20%20%20%20'%20file%20%20%20%20draft%20saved%20%20draft%20discarded%20%20community%20wiki%20%20hide%20preview%20%20Search%20using:%20%20(,[%5E,[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+)[a-zA-Z0-9]+:%20%20and%20replace%20using:%20%20%5C1:%20%20Here%20using%20a%20negated%20character%20class%20we%20are%20matching%20text%20that%20is%20not%20a%20comma%20or%20whitespace%20and%20capture%20it%20to%20be%20used%20as%20back-reference%20later.%20%20RegEx%20Demo%20%20Sed%20command:%20%20sed%20-E%20's/(,[%5E,[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+)[a-zA-Z0-9]+:/%5C1:/'%20file%20%20,ghjgc%20:%20Int)%20,ghjg,%20b:%20Int)%20%20%20%20As%20per%20comments%20below%20OP%20can%20use%20this%20sed%20command:%20%20sed%20-E%20'%20s/(,[%5E,[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+)[a-zA-Z0-9]+:/%5C1:/%20s/%5E.*func%20+//%20s/%20*-%3E.*$//%20'%20file%20%20Edit%20Summary%20%20added%20178%20characters%20in%20body%20%20cancel%20upvote%20%20flag%20%20I%20am%20using%20this%20regex%20in%20sed,%20to%20substitute.%20How%20can%20I%20use%20$1%20substitution%20there?%20%E2%80%93%20prabodhprakash%20%2056%20mins%20ago%20%20upvote%20%20flag%20%20Please%20see%20edit%20to%20question%20%E2%80%93%20prabodhprakash%20%2043%20mins%20ago%20%20upvote%20%20flag%20%20stackoverflow.com/questions/41039273/%E2%80%A6%20-%20reason%20for%20using%20sed%20like%20that.%20%E2%80%93%20prabodhprakash%20%2020%20mins%20ago%20%20%20upvote%20%20flag%20%20This%20part%20alone%20works%20fine,%20but%20when%20I%20put%20this%20into%20the%20original%20sed%20command%20(as%20I%20have%20in%20the%20question%20-%20it%20fails%20-%20other%20sed%20commands%20starts%20failing%20with%20-E%20in%20place)%20%E2%80%93%20prabodhprakash%20%2016%20mins%20ago%20%20%20upvote%20%20flag%20%20ideone.com/NyFMPW%20%E2%80%93%20prabodhprakash%20%207%20mins%20ago%20%20%20upvote%20%20flag%20%20cc%20b:%20remained%20as%20is.%20It%20should%20have%20become%20cc:%20%E2%80%93%20prabodhprakash%20%204%20mins%20ago%20%20ok,%20now%20check%20this%20demo%20%E2%80%93%20anubhava%20%201%20min%20ago%20%20edit%20%20ok,%20[now%20check%20this%20demo](http://ideone.com/brSi7L)%20%20Please%20avoid%20extended%20discussions%20in%20comments.%20Would%20you%20like%20to%20automatically%20move%20this%20discussion%20to%20chat?%20%20help%20enter%20at%20least%2015%20characters%20%20add%20a%20comment%20%7C)

Comment: I am using this regex in sed, to substitute. How can I use $1 substitution there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039273/shell-script-to-convert-a-string-from-one-form-to-another - reason for using sed like that.

Comment: This part alone works fine, but when I put this into the original sed command (as I have in the question - it fails - other sed commands starts failing with -E in place)

Comment: `cc b:` remained as is. It should have become `cc:`